# Adding Next Appointment Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, report

I have a recall report that produces letters for every patient who needs to return to the office on a certain date based on their recall plan (a plan that determines when they should return based on their condition). I have another table that stores all appointments for each patients (past and present). Appointments in the recall_plans table are auto-generated whereas appointments in the appointments table where created manually. The recall plan report is not checked if a person calls in to make an appointment so often the same appointment is represented in both tables resulting in duplicate reminder letters being sent out.

I need to do two things:
*(I know my approach is not necessarily resolving the business problem but this is what I am tasked with)*

1. I need to produce a list showing the
   next appointment for each patient
   but only if it is in the future.
2. I need to add a column to the first
   report showing each patient’s next
   appointment so someone can manually
   identify that duplicate letters
   would go out for specific patients
   and intervene accordingly.

Recall Report Query:

```
SELECT description as [Plan Name], 
per.first_name + ' ' + per.last_name as [Patient],
substring (plan_start_date, 5,2) + '-' +
substring (plan_start_date, 7,2) + '-' + 
substring (plan_start_date, 1,4) as [Plan Start Date],
substring (nr.expected_return_date, 5,2) + '-' +
substring (nr.expected_return_date, 7,2) + '-' + 
substring (nr.expected_return_date, 1,4) as [Expected Return Date] 
FROM recall_plan_mstr rp, 
patient_recall_plans nr, 
patient pt, 
person per
WHERE rp.practice_id = nr.practice_id 
and rp.recall_plan_id = nr.recall_plan_id 
and nr.practice_id = pt.practice_id 
and nr.person_id = pt.person_id 
and per.person_id = pt.person_id 
and (active_plan_ind = 'Y') 
and rp.practice_id = '0025'
```

Recall Report Results:

```
PLAN NAME          PATIENT          START      RETURN
------------------ ---------------- ---------- ----------
OFFICE VISIT W/ DR Charles Span     04-18-2011 12-15-2011
LIPID PANEL        Ronald Chap      04-11-2011 06-28-2011
OFFICE VISIT W/ DR Ronald Chap      04-11-2011 04-21-2011
OFFICE VISIT W/ DR Will Thor        03-31-2011 02-01-2012
PACEMAKER CHECK    Sylvia Berkly    05-03-2011 08-03-2011
OFFICE VISIT W/ DR Tim Cayle        04-13-2011 09-26-2011
OFFICE VISIT W/ DR Caferana Mercade 04-11-2011 10-08-2011
OFFICE VISIT W/ DR Susanna Calter   05-10-2011 05-07-2012
ICD CHECK          Jim Southern     04-14-2011 07-13-2011
STRESS ECHO        Don Cobey        04-28-2011 06-07-2010
```

Appointments Query:

```
select person_id, appt_date
from appointments 
where person_id is not null 
group by person_id, appt_date
order by person_id, appt_date desc
```

Appointments Results:

```
person_id                            appt_date
------------------------------------ ---------
073C8F83-CE15-4192-8E12-00006CB5A433 20091228
073C8F83-CE15-4192-8E12-00006CB5A433 20090510
073C8F83-CE15-4192-8E12-00006CB5A433 20090301
073C8F83-CE15-4192-8E12-00006CB5A433 20081006
378A281C-FAE7-43DF-BC03-00006E386680 20110509
378A281C-FAE7-43DF-BC03-00006E386680 20110217
378A281C-FAE7-43DF-BC03-00006E386680 20110124
378A281C-FAE7-43DF-BC03-00006E386680 20110111
378A281C-FAE7-43DF-BC03-00006E386680 20101207
816D4D31-3C99-4762-878D-000097883B73 20110316
816D4D31-3C99-4762-878D-000097883B73 20101216
```

Questions:

1. How can I produce a list from the
   appointments table that results with
   one patient per row with only the
   latest appointment that is in the
   future? Do I need to write a cursor
   for that?
2. How can I commingle this list into my
   recall report so it has a column to
   the right of return column that
   displays the patient’s next
   appointment date (future only)? Both
   tables have a person number GUID.

I hope I have adequately explained and provided enough information. If any additional information is needed please don’t hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is as follows:

```
SELECT person_id, min(appt_date) as appt_date
FROM appointments 
WHERE person_id is not null
   AND now() < appt_date -- This line is database specific
GROUP BY person_id
ORDER BY person_id
```

The answer to your second question is that you'll need a left join.  Left joins are easier if you use the join syntax everywhere.  Here is the query.

```
SELECT description as [Plan Name]
  , per.first_name + ' ' + per.last_name as [Patient]
  , substring (plan_start_date, 5,2) + '-' +
    substring (plan_start_date, 7,2) + '-' + 
    substring (plan_start_date, 1,4) as [Plan Start Date]
  , substring (nr.expected_return_date, 5,2) + '-' +
    substring (nr.expected_return_date, 7,2) + '-' + 
    substring (nr.expected_return_date, 1,4) as [Expected Return Date]
  , CASE
      WHEN next_appt.appt_date IS NULL
      THEN ''
      ELSE substring (next_appt.appt_date, 5,2) + '-' +
        substring (next_appt.appt_date, 7,2) + '-' + 
        substring (next_appt.appt_date, 1,4)
    END as [Next Appointment Date]
FROM recall_plan_mstr rp
  JOIN patient_recall_plans nr
    ON rp.recall_plan_id = nr.recall_plan_id
  JOIN patient pt
    ON nr.practice_id = pt.practice_id
      AND nr.person_id = pt.person_id 
  JOIN person per
    ON and per.person_id = pt.person_id
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT person_id, min(appt_date) as appt_date
        FROM appointments 
        WHERE person_id is not null
          AND now() < appt_date -- This line is database specific
        GROUP BY person_id
        ORDER BY person_id
      ) next_appt
    ON next_appt.person_id = pt.person_id
WHERE (active_plan_ind = 'Y') 
  AND rp.practice_id = '0025'
```

You'll note that I formatted the query for legibility.  See http://bentilly.blogspot.com/2011/02/sql-formatting-style.html for an explanation of why I choose to format SQL the way that I do.